# How to empty calendar trash via Google services

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

How can I empty a trash of a calendar via Google services?

I'm calling google services in Java (`com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar`) but I need to empty trash after I deleted events.

Comment: Do you mind to share with us what have you done? any codes?

Comment: I followed this sample in order to delete events:
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=mycalendartest-146913&duration=PT1H

Comment: Sorry, this is the correct url:
https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/calendar-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/cmdline/CalendarSample.java

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found the only way to solve this problem:

1. Create a temporary calendar
2. Move into this calendar all events that I have to delete
3. Delete the temporary calendar

Like this code:

```
Calendar entry = new Calendar();
entry.setSummary("MyTrashCalendar");
Calendar result = client.calendars().insert(entry).execute();
```

...

```
Event updatedEvent = client.events().move('currentCalendarId', "eventId", "destinationCalendarId").execute();
```

...

```
client.calendars().delete(calendar.getId()).execute();
```

I hope this helps